# Matplotlib - Why is my quiver plot always off?

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-algebra

I am trying to plot vectors using the quiver API in matplotlib.

I'm scratching my head because I am noticing the arrow tips don't end where they are supposed to.

For example, if I'm trying to plot a simple vector [2, 1], this is what I get.

[image]

Notice that the arrow is pointing a little past 2.0 in the x-direction and a little short of 1.0 in the y-direction.

Is this just an imperfection with the rendering? Or am I scaling something incorrectly?

Here is my code:

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Vector origin location
X = [0]
Y = [0]

# Directional vectors
U = [2]
V = [1]

# Creating plot
plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, color='b', units='xy', scale=1)
plt.title('Single Vector')

# x-lim and y-lim
plt.xlim(-2, 5)
plt.ylim(-2, 2.5)

# Show plot with gird
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

**UPDATE**

I am using PyCharm as my environment. I noticed that when I resize the window the arrow tip moves. Could this be my problem? How do I anchor this down?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my environment and GoogleColab, the arrows are displayed in the correct position. Are you using the latest version of MPL?

Comment: Reproducible with Python 3.6 matplotlib 2.0.0 and Python 3.8 matplotlib 3.4.2

Comment: I am using latest matplotlib. I just found something. Will post an update in a few minutes.

Comment: See update in original post. I think the window sizing is what's messing with it.

Comment: How about `plt.axis("equal")` then?

Answer (score 3):

I found this in the docs, in case it can help: *To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units as x and y, use `angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1`.*

Adding it to quiver seems to solve it, no matter the size of the window.